# Is there a sanctioned way to check if a method exists on an object instance in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a mix of object types which have one of two methods I need to invoke.  There is no common superclass or interface to distinguish which method to invoke, only a common method name/signature.

Currently I am using this approach (I realize the `if` conditional is extraneous here, just wanted to demonstrate what I've already tried):

```
// input is Object obj;

try {
  if ((obj as dynamic).firstFn is Function) {
    return obj.firstFn();
  }
} on NoSuchMethodError {
  // swallow the error
}

return obj.secondFn();
```

This approach *works* but is not ideal and breaks best practices as recommended by Dart (catching Errors is a no-no).  Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no approach which is *absolutely safe*, and none which doesn't require catching an error.

You have to do a dynamic member access, there is no way around that if you don't know the interface that you're accessing a member of.

If you do that, you *might* hit a getter instead of a method. The getter can have arbitrary side-effects and can throw anything. Or it can have a custom `noSuchMethod` method which intercepts a completely missing value, and does something weird.
But most likely, it'll either be there, or not, and throw a `NoSuchMethod` error in the latter case.

Any other behavior is just a risk you have to be willing to take. It's *probably* not a problem in practice, if the methods are named like methods, and the target is not being malicious.

So I'd also do:

```dart
int Function(int)? getFooFunction(Object o) { // or whatever type to expect.
  Object? tearOff;
  try {
    tearOff = (o as dynamic).foo;
  } on NoSuchMethodError {
    return null;
  } // Any other error is considered a real error.
  if (tearOff is int Function(int)) return tearOff;
  return null;  
}
```

You can even abstract this into a helper function:

```dart
extension SafeTearOff on Object {
  F? tryTearOff<F extends Function>(Object? Function(dynamic) tear) {
    Object? tearOff;
    try {
      tearOff = tear(this);
    } on NoSuchMethodError {
      return null;
    }
    if (tearOff is F) return tearOff;
    return null;
  }
}
```

which you can use as:

```dart
var foo = someValue.tryTearOff<int Function(int)>((o) => o.foo);
if (foo != null) {
  print(foo(42));
}
```